# How can I read from a document.txt lines with emoji and show them on terminal when I run the ruby code?

Tags: ruby, watir, emoji, browser-automation

I want to read a document file .txt in Ruby, but the following lines of this document contain emojis. When I run the program it shows me different symbols and not the actual emoji.

I have already tried different methods. How can I do this, should I install any gem??

```
file='document.txt'
```

This document contains the following line with emojis:

> This is a test line

```
  File.readlines(file).each do |line|      
      puts line
  end
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using, the encoding should be UTF by default.

Comment: Also does your terminal and font support the emojis? Can you copy/paste the emoji in to the terminal?

Comment: No my terminal does not support emojis i cant copy them when i paste it shows only ??

Comment: my version of ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x64-mingw32]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a rails issue, this is a terminal issue. You need a terminal emulator that support emoji, but more importantly you need a font with emoji support. Almost all terminal emulators except maybe cmd.exe on Windows *should* be able to display emoji, but nothing will happen without a font that has emoji.

For terminal emulators I recommend:
- cmder on Windows
- any of the VTE based terminals on Linux, or Kitty, alacritty etc

For fonts with emoji support that are also good for programming (ligature support, etc), I recommend:
- [Nerd Fonts](https://www.nerdfonts.com/)

Installers and instructions for Nerd Fonts are available on their website. These fonts include emoji, devicons, powerline, and other nice glyphs.